# Setwd in R with double backslashes \\

Tags: r

Quick one - I am a beginner in R Studio so trust asking a silly question .

What is the difference between the two code of setwd as not sure ? or is their any difference at all ?

```
> setwd("C:/Users/RAMIT PAUL/Downloads/Rate Cat")
> setwd("C:\\Users\\RAMIT PAUL\\Downloads\\Rate Cat")
```

Comment: Yes the latter will fail. You need to use the first or use double backslashes

Comment: @Firebug Where did OP make that clear?

Comment: @Firebug If you look at the [markdown of the first revision](https://superuser.com/revisions/19a12a4a-9142-4841-acc9-79e70d968e10/view-source) the double backslashes were there already then, but the markdown interpreted them as an escaped single backslashes. Besides the title explicitly said "Setwd in "R" with \\". So to me it looks like they mean double backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Any number of forward slashes will work (this is an OS thing). So the both the following will work:

```
setwd("C:/Users/RAMIT PAUL/Downloads/Rate Cat")
setwd("C://////////Users///////////RAMIT PAUL///////////Downloads///////////Rate Cat")
```

Now, backslashes are imbued with special meaning. They are used for escape sequences. So you have to escape the slash itself so it's correctly parsed. Hence, this won't work:

```
setwd("C:\Users\RAMIT PAUL\Downloads\Rate Cat")
```

While these work:

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\RAMIT PAUL\\Downloads\\Rate Cat")
setwd("C:\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\Users\\RAMIT PAUL\\Downloads\\Rate Cat")
```

---

In R 4.0.0 you can actually use (thanks [Mossa](https://superuser.com/users/1642512/mossa)):

```
setwd(r"(C:\Users\RAMIT PAUL\Downloads\Rate Cat)")
```

Comment: @user817995 You're welcome :). Please consider accepting my answer (clicking the green check mark below the score arrows) if it thoroughly answered all your inquiries.

Comment: Also add the `setwd(r"(C:\Users\RAMIT PAUL\Downloads\Rate Cat)")` that was introduced in R 4.0. See [this](https://mpopov.com/blog/2020/05/22/strings-in-r-4.x/#quotes)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip @Mossa! I haven't kept up with new R changes, that is nice to have